# Replacing placeholders [client_name] in a template PHP

Tags: php, smarty

I developing an invoice system with the option to design templates and save html code to database.

Now i'm in the phase to implement a template on the front end by user. Now the invoice data comes from the database using a foreach loop. I am stuck on how to get the values to replace the placeholder in this context. Below is an code extracted from my template:

```php
<tbody>
  <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  ?> 
    <tr>
      <td class="total-rown"><?php echo "[course_no_{$i}] "; ?></td>
      <td class="total-rown"><?php echo "[product_{$i}] "; ?></td>
      <td class="total-rown"><?php echo "[delegates_no_{$i}] "; ?></td>
      <td class="total-rown"><?php echo "[price_{$i}] [curr]"; ?></td>
      <td class="total-rown"><?php echo "[total_{$i}] [curr]"; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    }
  ?> 
...
```

How can i replace the dynamic placeholders above with actual values from the invoice database table when the user generates the invoice in pdf.

Comment: did you follow the [smarty crash course](https://www.smarty.net/crash_course)?   Because your placeholders do not look like the placeholders used in smarty.  (and I do think that a template does not contain PHP-code...)

Comment: I did not follow the smarty crash course

Comment: You did add the tag `smarty`. Would it not be logical that this question is about smarty templates? Or can you explain the relationship with smarty to this question ?

Comment: I wanted suggestion regarding smarty on this

Comment: It seems like there's really no benefit in using "special placeholders" here, only trouble really in trying to parse that, given that it's still mostly straight PHP.  Why not just toss in the data from the database and just loop the rows and have actual variables there. Otherwise, actually use Smarty and do it as one would in Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve. If you want to use composite variable names, you can just concatenate then print. E.g.:

```
<td class="total-rown"><?php  echo $row["total_{$i}"] . ' ' . $row['curr']; ?></td>
```

(where `$row` - is an associated array with values from the database)
etc.

But if you want to substitute arbitrary values into an arbitrary pattern (e.g where placeholders are denoted with square brackets) you can use a regular expression with a callback function, like in the example below:

```
<?php
  // Function
  function str_substitute($pattern, $values) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
      '/\[(.*?)\]/',
      function ($matches) use ($values) {
        // $matches[0] - the whole found string (including braces)
        // $matches[1] - the expression inside first parentheses (without braces)
        return array_key_exists($matches[1], $values) ? $values[$matches[1]] : $matches[0];
      },
      $pattern
    );
  }


  // List of values
  $values = [
    'total' => 1234,
    'curr' => 'USD'
  ];

  // Usage
  print str_substitute('[total] [curr] [wrongvalue]', $values);
  // Prints: 1234 USD [wrongvalue]
```

Comment: i know this. The thing is my template is a dynamic one which adds 5 rows to the invoice table with dynamic placeholders. How do i replace those with values from a database using foreach in php